# Shortcut to take photo on opening text message without user interaction

Tags: security, shortcut

I can create a shortcut on my Iphone 13 to take a photo when the text message app is opened but despite telling the shortcut not to ask before running it still comes up with a flag box telling me to tap to respond.  Can I get it just to take the photo?